# IF condition not working as expected - C Language

Tags: c, cs50

I have the below code in which the if condition does not seem to be working as expected.

as an example, if I enter 0.29 the results that are given are

Quarters: 1
Dimes: 0
Nickels: 4205264
Pennies: 4

As you can see this is incorrect as after the first if statement is performed 'if (cents >= 25)' this would leave a remainder of 4 which is stored in the 'cents' variable.  This should mean that the next two 'IF' statements return a '0' and the final if statement is carried out 'if (cents >= 1)'.  This is however not the case as you can see that Nickles is returning a value of 4205264.

When you enter 1.17 the result returns as expected:

Quarters: 4
Dimes: 1
Nickels: 1
Pennies: 2

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
float dollars;
int cents;
int quartersUsed;
int dimesUsed;
int nickelsUsed;
int penniesUsed;

do 
{ 
    dollars = get_float("Float: ");

    while (dollars <= 0) {
        dollars = get_float("Float: ");
    }

    cents = roundf(dollars * 100);
    printf("%i\n", cents);

    if (cents >= 25) {
        quartersUsed= cents / 25;
        cents = cents % 25;
    } 

    if (cents >= 10) {
       dimesUsed = cents / 10;
       cents = cents % 10;
    } 

    if (cents >= 5) {
       nickelsUsed = cents / 5;
       cents = cents % 5;
    } 

    if (cents >= 1) {
       penniesUsed = cents / 1;
       cents = cents % 1;
    } 

    printf("Quarters: %i\n",quartersUsed);
    printf("Dimes: %i\n",dimesUsed);
    printf("Nickels: %i\n",nickelsUsed);
    printf("Pennies: %i\n",penniesUsed);


}
while (dollars == false);

}
```

Comment: It is not terribly obvious what such an assignment was meant to teach.  A good outcome would be discovering that you don't need the if-statements at all.  Now the variable is always assigned and the bug disappears.  Fix dollars == false next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note that your *if* clauses not only are unnecessary, as they also may let some of your variables to be printed uninitialized (which is probably what is causing the problem in your output).** And just as you don't need all those condition checks, you don't need all those variables. Remember that C programmers tend to focus on the economy of operations and space whenever possible. Check my implementation below, compare it to yours, and try to guess how many operations and space it saves. (Since you didn't post your "cs59.h" library, I commented it and implemented a "get_float" function that always returns "1.17".)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include <cs50.h>

float get_float(const char *)
{
    return 1.17;
}

int main()
{
    float dollars;
    while((dollars = get_float("Float: ")) <= 0);

    int cents = (int) roundf(dollars * 100);
    printf("%i\n", cents);

    printf("Quarters: %i\n", cents / 25);
    printf("Dimes:    %i\n", (cents = cents % 25) / 10);
    printf("Nickels:  %i\n", (cents = cents % 10) / 5);
    printf("Pennies:  %i\n", cents % 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have run the code and works perfectly but I am a little confused on the mathematical equation side of things.  For example, if I enter 0.32 which is converted to 32 the result is Quarters: 1 Dimes:    0 Nickels:  1 Pennies:  2 (correctly), howver when I manually look to work out the formaula in this case the Nickels part I am doing 32 % 10 leaves 2, then 2/5 = 0.4 which would therefore not be a 1 for the Nickel?

Comment: Note that when I print the Dimes and the Nickels, I make assignments to the variable cents, so its value is updated (those assignments could be done outside the printf's, but I did them there for a matter of conciseness). If cents starts at 32, Quarters will print 32/25 (ie 1). Dimes will update cents to 32%25 (ie 7) then print 7/10 (ie 0). Nickels will update cents to 7%10 (ie 7) then print 7/5 (ie 1). Finally, Pennies will print 7%5 (ie 2). Let me know if you need further explanations!

Comment: Thanks, @jango for the clear explanation, really helped for me to get my head around it and makes perfect sense with why it is overkill using IF statements :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your classes =]

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize your variables, because if you don't enter in a if block, what is happening in your example, you end printing a variable that has been never intialized.

In C, no intialization is done for you so if you don't put a value in your variable, they will have an undefined value (depending on which value was there previously in memory).

Comment: Sorry, I may be misunderstanding your comment but the variable has been initialized in the global variable at the top of the code.  My understanding is that due to the scope chain the variable in the if statement has access to the global variable?  I am receiving no errors with regards to the variable being undefined

Comment: They are not global variables, but local to `main()`. So no, they have not been initialised.

Comment: So my understanding is that the variable (cents) within the if statement is a local variable but as it is initially defined outside of the if statement the global variable gets updated when the local variable is updated?

Comment: No, there are no global variables in this program at all. There is only automatic initialisation (to `0`) for global variables, which have to be defined *outside* of a function.

Comment: You have **declared** your variables, but not **initialized** them, initialize a variable is giving it a value : `int cents = 0;`

Comment: Alternatively you can remove all the conditionals, then every variable gets set. It doesn't matter whether there are at least 5 cents to calculate the nickels. If there are less than 5 cents then the arithmetic results in 0 nickels and still the same number of cents.

Comment: @Coder "Local variables" are the ones which are declared inside a function - here `main()`. If you declare all those variables outside `main()` i.e. before  `int main(void)`, they will be global. However, your code does not require any Globals. As @Adrien sugguested, initialisation will solve problem.